# My webpage messes up when re-sized

Tags: html, css, time, web

My webpage looks very awkward whenever I re-size it to any width length pass the absolute highest. Just check it out, it messes up in the header sections and I have no clue how to fix it. Please help me, this is my very first website and I'm starting to get a little furstrated by these simple things.

I don't know how to demonstrate it, but I'll just say that the personal sessions and contact buttons, when resized past a certain point end up under the header instead of embedded in the header, causing it to interfere with the content area. thank you!

Header Code:

```
<header>
        <div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png"></div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html"><img src="images/Home.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/Home2.jpg'"  onmouseout="this.src='images/Home.jpg'"></a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html"><img src="images/About.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/About2.jpg'"  onmouseout="this.src='images/About.jpg'"></a></li>
                <li><a href="plans.html"><img src="images/Plans.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/Plans2.jpg'"  onmouseout="this.src='images/Plans.jpg'"></a></li>
                <li><a href="nutrition.html"><img src="images/Nutrition.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/Nutrition2.jpg'"  onmouseout="this.src='images/Nutrition.jpg'"></a></li>
                <li><a href="personal-sessions.html"><img src="images/Personal-Sessions.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/Personal-Sessions2.jpg'"  onmouseout="this.src='images/Personal-Sessions.jpg'"></a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html"><img src="images/Contact.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='images/Contact2.jpg'"  onmouseout="this.src='images/Contact.jpg'"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

header{
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
background-color: black;
border-bottom: solid white;
box-shadow: 0 5px 30px #888888;
}

#logo{
background-image: url("images/logo.png");
float: left;
height: 100px;
color: white;
margin: 0;
margin-left: 40px;
padding: 14px 100px 0 115px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design/) 
To have your website less messed up, use % for width and sometimes for height as well and not pixels.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add viewport meta tag  and make your website responsive

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`